# Access Violation when function returns after fread() applyed to a local struct variable

Tags: c++, file-io, struct, fread

This is a part from my program.

```
void LookUpStuInfo(student stu[], int size, int ID) 
{   
    FILE *fp; 
    if((fp = fopen("stu_dat", "r")) == NULL)
    { 
        cout << "cannot open file" << endl;
        return; 
    } 

    struct student tmp;
    fread(&tmp, sizeof(struct student), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

stu_dat(created by `fwrite()`) stores information of several `struct student`. When this function ends and returns to `main()` function, access violation occurs.

However if I don't use a local struct variable in this case, instead using a student `stu[]` and apply `fread()` to `&stu[0]`, it works fine. So what's wrong?

Well, the code above is enough to produce an access violation. I've tested to delete all the other code in this LookUpStuInfo() until only basic read and close is left, still won't work.

So the following is the complete code of this project.It may help if you want to know details about `main()` and `struct student`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include "stdio.h"
#define num 3
using namespace std;
struct student
{
    int ID;
    string name;
    string sex;
    string birthday;
    float score;
};
void SortStuArr(student stu[], int size)
{
    student tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (int j = (i + 1); j < size; j++)
        {
            if (stu[i].score < stu[j].score)
            {
                tmp = stu[i];
                stu[i] = stu[j];
                stu[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    cout << "ID" << "    " << "Score" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << stu[i].ID << "\t" << stu[i].score << endl;
}
float GetAvgScr(student stu[], int size)
{
    float avg=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        avg += (stu[i].score);
    avg = avg / size;
    return avg;
}
void LookUpStuInfo(const char* locat, int size, int ID)
{
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp=fopen("stu_dat","r"))==NULL)
    {
        cout << "cannot open file" << endl;
        return;
    }
    struct student tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        fread(&tmp, sizeof(struct student), 1, fp);
        if (tmp.ID == ID)
        {
            cout << tmp.name << tmp.ID << tmp.sex << tmp.birthday << tmp.score << endl;
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }
    cout << "Not Found!" << endl;
    fclose(fp);
}
void WritetoFile(student stu[], int size)
{
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp=fopen("stu_dat","w+"))==NULL)
    {
        cout << "cannot open file" << endl;
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        fwrite(&stu[i], sizeof(struct student), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}



int main()
{
    student stu[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cin >> stu[i].name >> stu[i].ID >> stu[i].sex >> stu[i].birthday >> stu[i].score;
    }
    cout << GetAvgScr(stu, num) << endl;
    WritetoFile(stu, num);

        LookUpStuInfo("stu_dat", num, 1000);
    return 0;
}
```

Well I've tested to remove all `string` in my program and it works fine. It seems `fread()` will go wrong in a function with the operation on `string`.

Comment: `tmp` goes out of scope when the function ends.

Comment: You need to post a complete example of your problem.  Without that, any solution is really just a guess.

Comment: What is the point of reading to `tmp` and then doing nothing with it?  This function does little more than open and close a file for no apparent reason.  On its own I doubt that it is the cause of your problem.

Comment: You appear to have simplified your actual code when asking the question.  This is good, but I fear you have simplified the problem away.  Does this actual code show the problem?  Please include the code of main

Comment: Not related to your problem, but I would nonetheless advise `FILE *fp = fopen("stu_dat", "r") ;
    if( fp == NULL )` and also `sizeof(tmp)` rather than `sizeof(struct student)`.  That not the only "style" comment I might make, but that's enough for starters.

Comment: @Martin Bonner Thank you. I've added it to my post. And I've found the problem occurs mainly when 'fread()' operates on 'string'. Still don't know what implement of 'fread()' and 'string' causes this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `fread` into a `std::string` like `student.name` (or fwrite from it).  The crash occurred because you had a corrupted string and when the compiler attempted to copy it into the array it all went horribly wrong.  Reading straight into the array wouldn't have helped because presumably you were planning to access the members of the array at some point - at which point everything would have died again.

You will need to read in the length of the string, then read the characters of the string in.